# Setting transform.eulerAngles doesn't work in a StateMachineBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an attack for boss fight where a projectile spins progressively faster around the player's position before settling on a random rotation and directly targeting the player. As of this moment the only part of the attack I've implemented is the spinning. However, while it is moving around the player correctly, it is not rotating to point towards them. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FBHCircle : StateMachineBehaviour
{

    private float rotationValue;

    [SerializeField] private float maxSpeed;
    private float currentSpeed;

    [SerializeField] private float radius;

    // OnStateEnter is called when a transition starts and the state machine starts to evaluate this state
    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        rotationValue = 0;
    }

    // OnStateUpdate is called on each Update frame between OnStateEnter and OnStateExit callbacks
    override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        currentSpeed = maxSpeed * 4 * stateInfo.normalizedTime * (1 - stateInfo.normalizedTime);
        rotationValue += currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        animator.transform.position = GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position + (radius * new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(rotationValue), Mathf.Cos(rotationValue)));
        animator.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.forward * rotationValue;
    }

}
```

Right now, setting `animator.transform.position` is giving me no problems, but setting `animator.transform.eulerAngles` does not work at all. I had this problem as well with a different attack, but I thought it was just related to exit time or something and I left the problem for later. Now, I don't think that it's related to exit time at all. I also checked in the inspector to make sure that it wasn't rotating by a very small amount, but it still turned out it just wasn't rotating at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also realized right after posting this question that I forgot to mention that the projectile's rotation is not being set through the actual animation. It is only being set through the script and nothing else.
[image: A screenshot of the scene - the projectile is still at its default rotation]

Comment: Please include an image showing the local axes of the projectile. Have you tried using `animator.transform.LookAt(playerTransform);` instead of editing `eulerAngles`? By the way, try to avoid calling `GameObject.Find` every update - it's best to call it once and cache the result.

Comment: Was does `does not work at all` mean exactly?

Comment: The projectile is always at its default rotation.

Comment: Your `maxSpeed` is set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's set to 4 at the moment. There are no problems with the circular movement, just the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and a lot of trial and error, I managed to figure it out. In a few other animation clips I did indeed rotate it through an animation property. Despite this being on a completely separate animation, it still locked me out of altering the eulerAngles within the StateMachineBehaviour script for a completely different animation. I removed the rotation from the other animations and it worked!... sort of. I have a different problem now, including the fact that I removed the rotation from the other animations, but I can manage it now.